# python Django custom error msg for any error (apart from try,except)

Tags: python, django

in django, whenever an error is occured , if we dont keep in try block, an error will be raised . At that point of time(during error), if it is not in try block, instead of the error page, can we display a msg .

What I am actually saying is, is there anything in django(like signals) that gets activated during error and prints that msg . In my case, it is an ajax request, so what i want is, when something is not inside try block, and still if it raises error, then it should atleast send back an error msg(to another server which made ajax call to our server) saying "error occured" .

Comment: Generally you don't want your error messages propagating to the user and furthermore, if an exception is raised without being caught it naturally will stop the process, so there won't be a response. You could set up [Sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/sentry/) to catch your exceptions; it's a great way of monitoring errors & logging etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, if an error occurs, it isn't actually propagated to the user automatically.  Rather, if you have an error occur, it returns a 500 error page.  If Django is in debug mode, it will give a traceback.  If the other server is intelligent, it will realized that there is a 500 error message instead of a 200 message.  In Django you can then define a "500.html" in your root directory to handle the errors (or use the default Django template).  GLHF

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to globally override the default exception handling in Python. You can use `try`/`except` blocks to catch errors, execute some code, then re-raise the exception though.

Put your code in a `try` block, and in the `except` block print your message, then call `raise` to re-raise the caught exception.

Ex:

```
try:
    raise Exception("This is an exception")
except Exception:
    print ("Exception raised, notify server")
    #re-raise exception
    raise
```

This will print something like:

```
Exception raised, notify server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[file]", line [line], in [module]
Exception: This is an exception
```

Comment: There actually is.  If you want to catch all exceptions, put a try, except around all your code (or the function that envelopes all the code.)

Comment: Well yes, but then you lose the ability to give specific error messages and recover gracefully since you would have no idea where in the code the exception occurred.